# Encapsulation in a Composition Class C++

Tags: c++, oop, methods, encapsulation, friend

I have a map class, which contains a vector containing MapEntitys. MapEntity is a class of which Factory, Farm and 3 other classes are inherited from.

These 5 classes both should be "ticked" every few seconds, at which point they will all do a function individual to each class, but only the map class should be able to "tick" them.

How would I support this type of encapsulation in C++? Friends? Should I just use public methods and not misuse the methods? (Although I would prefer proper encapsulation for good practice, even though this code will not be re-distributed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically you could use any of that.

However, if *MapEntities* are to be "ticked" from outside, the `tick` method should be part of their public methods. Actually, it should be a virtual public method of the `MapEntity` class.

And yes, public methods are proper encapsulation. They tell the user of your class what it can do. In this case, the user is the `Map` class and it can `tick` MapEntities.

You should consider other solutions (friends, anonymous namespaces etc.) only if `MapEntities` are **designed** to be used only by `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `friend`, but I think it's better to not put any restriction on what can 'tick' your MapEntity classes.

It's generally considered bad practice to put artificial limitations in your code. Even though you only want your map class to be able to call this function right now, this might change in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought putting limits on code was the right thing to do :s

Comment: No, the reason for using encapsulation is protecting data, not putting limits on code. You normally use encapsulation when you want to protect data, usually to enforce side effects of the data changing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `friend` would actually lower the degree of encapsulation, since your map class would see any privates of `MapEntities`, not only the `tick` method.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your task looks like design-pattern visitor description.

```
class Visitor;

class MapEntity
{
  public:
    virtual void tick(Visitor &v) = 0;
};

class Factory: public MapEntity
{
  public:
    void accept(Visitor &v);
    // ...
};

class Farm: public MapEntity
{
  public:
    void tick(Visitor &v);
    // ...
};

class Mill: public MapEntity
{
  public:
    void tick(Visitor &v);
    // ...
};

class Visitor
{
  public:
    virtual void visit(Factory *e) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Farm *e) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Mill *e) = 0;
};

void Factory::tick(Visitor &v) { v.visit(this); }
void Farm::tick(Visitor &v) { v.visit(this); }
void Mill::tick(Visitor &v) { v.visit(this); }

class SomeVisitor: public Visitor
{
    void visit(Factory *e) { /* ... */ };
    void visit(Farm *e) { /* ... */ };
    void visit(Mill *e) { /* ... */ };
};

class OtherVisitor: public Visitor  { /* ... */ };
```

client code:

```
MapEntity *enities[];
// ...
SomeVisitor v1;
OtherVisitor v2;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  entities[i].tick(v1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  entities[i].tick(v2);
}
```